# unable to read gpio pin status

Tags: python, gpio

I have been trying to read the current state of an output gpio pin on a raspberry pi but without success

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time


GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)


while True:

    if GPIO.output(4) == True:
        print "pin is high"
    else:
        print "pin is low"

    time.sleep(0.500)
```

I keep getting an error telling me that on my first line of the if statement i need two arguments, which if i supply two arguments all that happens is the pin goes to high and continues printing on the loop. I'm sure ive got to be close but i just cant seem to get it.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to double check the status of your pin and not measure it.

I have the situation that two addons (under Kodi/XBMC) can control a pin and before one of them changes the settings it needs to read the status of this pin first:

```
if GPIO.input(17) is 1:
    line2 = 'The pin is high'
else:
    line2 = 'The pin is low'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you need to change

```
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)
```

to

```
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN)
```

if you want to read from it

GPIO pins are not duplex (they can read or write but not both) ... you must explicitly change it to write mode to write and read mode to read ...

Comment: that makes sense.. in that case i will just fork the physical connection, send one leg to the device it was connecting to originally and send the other to an input pin and read the pin status that way. Thanks for the quick answer!